How do I check what version of JetBrains a remote server is using?
I'm using JetBrains Gateway with PyCharm to work directly on an EC2 instance and I just updated my local version of PyCharm to the latest version, but it's not clear to me if the remote server also updated or not. How can I check?

I eventually figured this out:

start a PyCharm project that connects to the remote server,
open a terminal and run ps aux | grep "pycharm"
Look for a line that says something like ...pycharm-professional-XXX.XXXXX.XXX/... (see below for an example).




Those numbers at the end are the "build number" of PyCharm that is running on the remote server.
You can then go to the PyCharm "Other Versions" page to look for that build number and see what version of PyCharm it's for.

For example, the build number in the screenshot above corresponds to PyCharm version 2024.1.
Related: Where can I find the build number for every version of Jetbrains released in the past?



